# Медленная прокрутка одного блока при прокрутке страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

На странице есть два блока — при прокрутке страницы первый прокручивается как обычно, а второй должен скролиться медленно. Как такое возможно сделать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let last_known_scroll_position = 0;
let ticking = false;

function moveHint(scroll_pos) {
  hint.style.setProperty('--top', scroll_pos / 8 + "px");
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  last_known_scroll_position = window.scrollY;

  if (!ticking) {
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      moveHint(last_known_scroll_position);
      ticking = false;
    });

    ticking = true;
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 3000px;
  background: url(https://loremflickr.com/320/240);
  background-size: 100%;
}

#hint {
  --top: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  top: var(--top);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url(https://loremflickr.com/100/100);
}
```

```html
<div id="hint">
```